# JBoss 7.1 Spring Boot Logging

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, jboss

I'm running JBoss 7.1.6 on Java 11.

I've successfully deployed a Spring Boot 2.5.2 WAR file but the logging is very strange. I'm using Spring Boot's default logging provider Logback. I have a very standard logback.xml file located externally. Here is an excerpt from logback.xml:

```
<logger name="com.sun" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="org.apache" level="INFO"/>
<logger name="org.springframework" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.core.env" level="DEBUG"/>
<logger name="org.springframework.jndi" level="ERROR"/>
```

I'm adding system properties to the standalone.xml file to point to my external configurations:

```
<property name="javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory" value="com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl"/>
<property name="javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory" value="com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl"/>
<property name="javax.xml.transform.Transformer" value="com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl"/>
<property name="spring.config.additional-location" value="file:/path/to/folder/"/>
<property name="spring.profiles.active" value="dev"/>
```

I also have a jboss-deployment-destructure.xml defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
  <deployment>
    <dependencies>
      <system export="true">
        <paths>
          <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/serializer"/>
          <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/dtm"/>
          <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/dtm/ref"/>
          <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc"/>
          <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/dom"/>
          <path name="com/sun/org/apache/xalan/internal/xsltc/runtime"/>
        </paths>
      </system>
    </dependencies>
    <exclude-subsystems>
      <subsystem name="jaxrs"/>
    </exclude-subsystems>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-core"/>
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-annotations"/>
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jackson-databind"/>
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jdk8"/>
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.jackson-datatype-jsr310"/>
      <module name="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.jackson-jaxrs-json-provider"/>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider"/>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider"/>
      <module name="org.apache.commons.logging"/>
      <module name="org.apache.log4j"/>
      <module name="org.apache.xalan"/>
      <module name="org.apache.xerces"/>
      <module name="org.apache.xml-resolver"/>
      <module name="org.slf4j"/>
      <module name="org.slf4j.ext"/>
      <module name="org.slf4j.impl"/>
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

All of the classes that I've developed log fine, but I'm not seeing any logs from the third party deps i.e. org.springframework, org.apache, etc.

Comment: That's because of the way JBss EAP logs. It has a logging subsystem it uses to configure it's own logging.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to fix this?

Comment: There is no easy way to have log4j2 take over as the log manager. It involves editing JAR's and removing the logging subsystem. However that would not be supported.